# How big should a hash table be as a function of the maximum number of items?

Tags: hashtable

Basically I just want to know how big a hash table should be compared to the predicted number of items going into it.

Comment: It depends on what type of hashing you are using, what hash function(s) you employ, and what your tolerance for collisions is. Too big, and you waste memory. Too small, and you waste time dealing with collisions.

Comment: So it's really just up to preference then.  The reason I asked is: it is a review question for a test.  They said that it should be 1.5 to 2 times the maximum number of items, but I was curious to see if there is a general method used to get the size.

Comment: Depends pn the nature of collision resolusion. Separate chaining allows load-factors of > 1, linear probing (or other rehashing schemes) does not.

Comment: maybe interesting? performance values for various hash functions. https://exascale.info/assets/pdf/students/RashmiBakshi.pdf